# Multivariable limit using polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {2\sin (x^2 + y^2) + y^3}{3x^2+3y^2}$$

I am actually very new to polar coordinates so I'm a little bit confused about this part. I substitute this into this:
$\frac {2sin (r^2) + (r cos \theta)^3}{3r^2}$
But I am not even sure if it's right and what should I do after this.
Does the limit even exist? I need an explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Usually one takes $x = r \cos\theta$ and $y = r \sin\theta$. It's possible to take it the other way around, but that will confuse people. Except for that, you're correct so far. Now split the expression into two terms. Notice that $\sin(r^2)/r^2$ is a standard limit. For the second term, simplify it and notice that you get $r$ multiplied with something bounded. Its limit will therefore be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}  \frac{2\sin(x^2+y^2)+y^3}{3x^2+3y^2} &= \lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{2\sin(r^2)+r^3\sin^3\theta}{3r^2}\\
&=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{2\sin(r^2)}{3r^2} + \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r^3\sin^3\theta}{3r^2}\\
&= \frac{2}{3} + \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r\sin^3\theta}{3}\\
&= \frac{2}{3} + 0\\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}